# Simple calculator is not printing the answer?

Tags: java

My program's not working. What do you think is wrong?

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter first number: ");
    double num1 = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter second number: ");
    double num2 = in.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter operation to perform: ");
    String oper = in.next();

    if(oper == "add" || oper == "addition" || oper == "+") {
        double sum = num1 + num2;
        System.out.printf("The sum of the two numbers is %d", sum);
    }
```

When I type the operation(which is a String), program terminates. Output:

```
Enter first number: 12
Enter second number: 8
Enter operation to perform: 
"add"

Process completed.
```

I can't seem to find the error, please help?

Comment: try typing add without " AND do what the others say: Strings and "==" = bad idea!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @jlordo with the addition, that he is typing " on the console. `"add"` will never equal `add`. Using equals or == ...

Comment: All the answers about == are correct.  Thiss is one of the true stupidities of the java language.  In an attempt to be "correct" they built a trap for new users.  Most other languages make ths wok as expected, ome times introducing === for what Java does with ==. Getting this wrong is not your fault, everybody gets it wrong at first.

Answer (score 4):

Never compare strings with operator `==` - it is rough mistake. Use `equals` instead:

`if(oper.equals("add") || oper.equals("addition") || oper.equals("+")) {`

Comment: @NabilKadimi see other answers. There are good explanations already.

Comment: What makes this response 4 times better than the others that contain more explanation?

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `==` use the equals method :

```
if(oper.equals("add") || oper.equals("addition") || oper.equals("+"))
```

`==` operator is used to compare address in memory space rather than the content of the strings being compared

Answer (score 2):

Don't compare Strings using `==`. Always use `equals()`:

```
if("add".equals( oper ) || "addition".equals( oper ) || "+".equals( oper ) ) {

// ...
}
```

With `==` you compare object references (or primitive types). Strings are objects in Java, so when you compare `oper` and `add`, both point to different objects. Thus even if they contain the same value, the comparison with `==` fails, because they are still different objects.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(oper == "add" || oper == "addition" || oper == "+") {
```

should be

```
if(oper.equals("add") || oper .equals("addition") || oper.equals("+")) {
```

use `.equals` method to check if two strings are **meaningfully equal**, `==` operator just checks if two reference variables refer to the same instance.

Answer (score 1):

Don't compare `String`s using `==`. Use `equals` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Compare strings by using `equals(..)`  not `==`

replace

```
if(oper == "add" || oper == "addition" || oper == "+") {
```

by

```
if(oper.equals("add") || oper.equals("addition") || oper.equals("+")) {
```

`==` compares for same reference not same content.

Answer (score 1):

Do what all the others say: use `equals` or even `equalsIgnoreCase`. (There are good explanations for this so in the other answers. Would be silly to repeat it here.)

AND type "add" without the " in the console.

Only doing both will work.

Comment: Good find! Missed the `"` part.

Comment: Everyone was too quick to just jump on the beginner mistake of falling into the == trap.

Comment: @PeterWooster :) Thx It just jumped into my eye and nobdy seemed to notice.

Comment: Downvote? Seriously? Why for Walhall's sake? At least you could drop a comment, why you think this is a bad answer!

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
    if("add".equals(oper)  || "addition".equals(oper) || "+".equals(oper)) {
double sum = num1 + num2;
        System.out.printf("The sum of the two numbers is %d", sum);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `equals()` or still better `equalsIgnore()` instead of `==` for strings, you also need to enter `add` in the `command-line` instead of `"add"`.

Or else, you have to compare it as:

```
oper.equals("\"add\"")
```

Also, you seem to be from a `C` background. Normally in Java, one would use:

```
System.out.println("The sum of the two numbers is " + sum);
```

instead of

```
System.out.printf("The sum of the two numbers is %d", sum);
```

since `%d` prints `integer` value and `not double` value.

Comment: you mean `oper.equals("\"add\"")` because yours won't compile.

Comment: Ohh yeah.. It seems Regex still running at the back of my mind :)

Comment: I thought regex was in your head. But even for a regex it would be wrong, because `"\\"add\\""` is not a valid string literal and would not compile. You would have needed `"\\\"add\\\""`

Comment: In that case, I really got something new to learn.. Thanks a lot!